# How to debug external native library on Windows from Android Studio?

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-studio

I am trying to debug (from Windows) a native library (built with NDK v13b) that is shipped inside an Android application. The library is built outside of Android Studio, it does not use Gradle (CMake is used).

My library is built with debugging; the debug configuration in Studio is Hybrid, and I give the appropriate symbol directories. To "import" my library, I simply copy the `.so` and the `.jar` files inside my project directory in the appropriate locations (`libs` for the JAR, `jniLibs` for the SO).

When the library is built on a separate machine (Linux), I can do step-by-step without any problem, as long as I remap source locations (ie. using `settings set target.source-map`).

However, when I build the library on my Windows system, step-by-step does not work anymore.

I noticed a difference of behavior depending when I debug using the "built-from-Linux" or the "built-from-Windows" library. When debugging using the from-Linux one, LLDB command `image list` indicates that the library path is in the initial build directory. However, when debugging the from-Windows one, It is in `C:\Users\foo\.lldb\module_cache\remote-android\.cache...`. And this version of the library seems to be stripped.

Why this difference of behavior?
How can I either 1. use a pristine copy of my library in the module cache, or 2. directly use the build library?

Thanks,

Comment: i will say get a library that is not stripped.

Comment: @DUntouchable That's actually the point of my question. How do I do so that Android Studio/lldb chooses the version that is not stripped?

Comment: Though not a good way to do it, just rename the file that Android is picking , so it will pick the other one now.

Comment: @DUntouchable I think there is confusion. The library I build is not stripped initially, but the build system generates a stripped version of my library which is put on the phone. When debugging, lddb should use the initial version of the library, but instead downloads the version on the phone, which is stripped. I fail to see how renaming a file will address the problem.